# HTML5 create URL from form selection

Tags: html, forms, url

I have a user management site which I'd like to have "better" URLs. In essence, the client will be presented with a list of users, they pick one and they can view that user's page. So I have two options:

1. I can present the user with a literal list of URLs like this and have it scroll:

   ```
   <ul style="height:300px;overflow:auto">
   <li><a href="/profiles/1">User 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="/profiles/2">User 2</a></li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. I can present the user with a slightly more user friendly form/selection like this:

   ```
   <form action="/profiles/" method="GET">
   <select name="user">
   <option value="1">User 1</option>
   <option value="2">User 2</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit">
   </form>
   ```

I have likes and dislikes for both, what I really want is the best of both worlds:

1. I want to have "pretty" URLs like `/profiles/1`.
2. I want to have the UI be like a simple drop down where the user can just type the first few chars of the item and it will jump to it. (That last part is kinda  big deal there are 1000's of users). It doesn't have to be precisely this, but something equivalent in usability.
3. I'm not a fan of URLs which look like `/profiles/?user=1` when they can be `/profiles/1`.

So far the best I have been able to come up with is to have `/profiles/?user=1` seemlessly redirect to `/profiles/1`. So the user experience is smooth, but I am curious if someone can do better :-).

Ideas?

Comment: Your implies that if you use form element, you are stuck with the default url structure. Are you restricted from using javascript?

Comment: I would javascript is fair game, but if someone has a more creative solution I'd be interested in that too.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you want to avoid javascript in the name of being a clever bastard, you could use a css :hover pseudo-class to expand a div containing typical anchor tags. Something like:

```
.dropdown_parent {
    height:1.25em;
    width:100px;
    display: inline_block;
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown {
    max-height:1.25em;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height:1.25em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
.dropdown:hover {
    max-height:10em;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown_parent>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a>link</a>
        <a>link</a>
        <a>link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that I have not tested this at all.

More seriously, javascript is pretty much the way to go for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your option 2 (generate URL via form) you can try something like:

```
<form id="urlForm" onsubmit="this.action = '/profiles/' + this.user.options[this.user.selectedIndex].value;" method="GET">
<select id="user">
<option value="1">User 1</option>
<option value="2">User 2</option>
<option value="3">User 3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

but browsers may not allow this type of script to run by default, and it won't of course work at all if scripting is turned off or not available.
In my testing, this worked in Chrome, failed on Firefox, and IE prompted me to accept the script running.

It would be useful if there was a new HTML5 output attribute so you could calculate the contents of the form/@action, but I guess there are all sorts of security issues around this.

Comment: interesting approach, i'll give it a try and see what happens :-)